# Add .so files to a react native project (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, libc++

I'm working on an android app with react native, and after a while I switched to native code to import and use my own SDK. The problem is that I can't execute and I have this:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
```

The SDK provides shared library(.so file), and I have no interest in excluding these files by putting in the gradle "pickfirst or exclude ..." because otherwise the application encounters bugs and in fact it cannot use the SDK. Is there a solution to connect Reactnative with .so files?? THANKS

Comment: Hi there @OmarBenjelloun, I'm also trying to do the same, did you find any way to work it out, if yes then can you mention the steps and answer your own question??